# How to Save to Roaming Profile using ConfigurationManager in C#

Tags: c#, settings, profile, configurationmanager, roaming-profile

I'm trying to save a string to the AppSettingsSection of the current application's default configuration in the roaming profile using ConfigurationManager (ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoaming).

When I'm saving to the local profile (ConfigurationUserLevel.None) it works just fine.

```
// Write Name in NameSaved Section of AppSettings
public void WriteNameToAppSettings(string nameToSave)
{
    // Open Config File
    Configuration configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoaming); // ConfigurationUserLevel.None (local) is working just fine...

    // Add or Update NameSaved Section of AppSettings
    if ((configuration.AppSettings.Settings["NameSaved"]?.Value) == null)
        configuration.AppSettings.Settings.Add("NameSaved", nameToSave);
    else
        configuration.AppSettings.Settings["NameSaved"].Value = nameToSave;

    //  Save and Refresh Config File            
    configuration.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
    ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection(configuration.AppSettings.SectionInformation.Name);
}

// Set LastEnteredName Property from NameSaved Section of AppSettings
public void ReadNameFromAppSettings()
{
    // Read Config File and then Get Name LastEntered Section of AppSettings
    LastEnteredName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NameSaved"]?.ToString() ?? ""; // If null default to ""
}
```

The error I'm getting is:
System.InvalidOperationException: 'ConfigurationSection properties cannot be edited when locked.'

Any clues on how to fix this?